# Passing argument 2 of 'fibonacci' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, fibonacci, pass-by-value, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Fibonacci

void fibonacci(int n, int *fibs[n]){

    int i;
    *fibs[0] = 1;
    *fibs[1] = 1;

    printf("%d %d ", *fibs[0], *fibs[1]);

    for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
        *fibs[i] = *fibs[i-1] + *fibs[i-2];
        printf("%d ", *fibs[i]);
    }   
}

int main(){

    int n, i;

    printf("How many fibonacci numbers do you want to enter?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int fibs[n];

    fibonacci(n, &fibs);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was writing a Fibonacci program in this way. The program runs but does not print anything. And I get the error like, `[Warning] passing argument 2 of 'fibonacci' from incompatible pointer type`
How can I fix this program to run efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a variable length array

```
int fibs[n];
```

In this call

```
fibonacci(n, &fibs);
```

the argument has the type `int ( * )[n]`.

However the corresponding function parameter

```
void fibonacci(int n, int *fibs[n]){
```

has the type `int **` (due to adjusting by the compiler the parameter having array type to pointer to the array element type).

So the compiler issues the message.

The function declaration can be much simpler

```
void fibonacci(int n, int fibs[n]){
```

And in this case the function is called like

```
fibonacci(n, fibs);
```

Of course you will need to change the body of the function.

Pay attention to that this loop

```
for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
```

can result in accessing memory outside the passed array when `i` is equal to `n` because the valid range of indices is `[0, n)`.

And the first two Fibonacci numbers are `0` and `1`.

Even in the very beginning of the function

```
int i;
*fibs[0] = 1;
*fibs[1] = 1;
```

you need to check whether n is not less than 2.

The function can look for example like

```
void fibonacci( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 1 ) ) a[0] = 0;
    if ( !( n < 2 ) ) a[1] = 1;

    for ( size_t i = 2; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
    }
}
```

and called like

```
size_t n = 0;

printf("How many fibonacci numbers do you want to enter?: ");
scanf( "%zu", &n );

if ( n != 0 )
{
    int fibs[n];

    fibonacci( fibs, n );
}
```